# have dynamic amount in stripe pay button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I could not find any tutorial regarding this. I have a text field for inputting amount and insted of a submit btn I have the usual stripe "Pay with card" btn which when clicked will dispplay a popup with form and a pay btn with the amount mentioned eg "Pay $5.00" . How can I dynamically add amount to that btn ?

```
    = form_tag client_topup_index_path do
      = label_tag 'amount', 'To Pay', class: 'amount'
      = text_field :topup, :amount, class: 'test'
      %script.stripe-button{"data-amount" => @amount * 100, "data-description" => "Your payment description", "data-key" => ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'], :src => "https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"}
- content_for :footer_js do
  :javascript
    $(".me").on('click', function(){
      $(".me").data("amount","3");
      alert($('.sus').val());
    });
```

I tried to update the data-amount when data was entered into the text field but I could not do it. Currenlty the @amount is gettng data from the controller which is hard coded.

Comment: Please attempt something and put your attempt in your question, along with a description of the problem, ie why your attempt is not working.  Assume that nobody knows anything at all about the tutorial you are looking at.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, thanks for poinitng that out. I have updated the question.

Comment: Are you asking how to change a value on a html element?

Comment: @DickieBoy, no .I am trying to achieve something like kickstarter has. In kickstarter you can add the amount  then click on continue then fill the rest of the card details and thats all.

Comment: @DickieBoy, me trying to change the value on the html element was to figuring it out if it could be done that way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a click handler on the button that you want to kick off your function.  then find the element you want to update and call .val() on it to update the value.

```
$(".me").on('click', function(){
      value = $(".me").data.amount;
      $( ".classToUpdate" ).val(value);
    });
```

or something like that. This assumes that the button firing the event has the .me class and the div that should contain the value has the classToUpdate class.